# How to declare linked lists with pointers in Cython

Tags: python, c, pointers, linked-list, cython

I am trying to create a linked list in Cython for the following C code:

```
typedef struct my_struct *my_val;

typedef struct my_struct {
      int i;
      my_val next_val;
}
```

This didn't work:

```
 cdef my_struct* my_val

 cdef struct bc_struct:
      int i
      my_val next_val
```

I get this error on the first `cdef`:

```
'my_val' is not a type identifier
```

Neither did this:

```
cdef struct my_struct* my_val
```

This gives an error on the first `cdef`:

```
Syntax error in struct or union definition
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

From what i have read so far [`cdef`](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#c-variable-and-type-definitions) is not the equivalent of a `typedef`. Instead you are declaring `C` variables. Try using `ctypedef` instead as descriped in the link.

EDIT: A bit more explanation.
When you use `cdef mystruct* my_val` you are not performing a `typedef`, instead you are declaring the `C` variable `my_val` which is of type `mystruct *`. When you now try to use it as a type specifier like in your class, it of course tells you that it is not a specifier since it is a variable. If you use `ctypedef` instead it performs a typedef

```
ctypedef mystruct *my_val
```

for the second `cdef struct mystruct* my_val` it throws a syntax error because the syntax is `cdef` *type* *name* and thus you try to initialize a variable called `mystruct*` of type `struct` and have also a trailing `my_val` expression behind it.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. Replacing the `cdef`s with `ctypedef`s worked.